# How to have bolded headers, but non-bolded cells - filled with worksheet.append_table of pygsheets==2.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

The python3 (pygsheets 2.0.1) script below will bold all the cells starting at `A2.`
Is there an easy way (i.e., in one command) to ask for all these cells not to be bolded?

### Code:

```
import boto3, botocore
import datetime
import json
import pygsheets

currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())

def create_spreadsheet(outh_file, spreadsheet_name = "jSonar AWS usage"):
    client = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file=outh_file, outh_nonlocal=True)
    spread_sheet = client.create(spreadsheet_name)
    return spread_sheet


def get_regions():
    region = "us-west-1"
    regions = dict()

    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=region)
    ec2_responses = ec2.describe_regions()

    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=region)
    for resp in ec2_responses['Regions']:
        region_id = resp['RegionName']
        tmp = '/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/%s/longName' % region_id
        ssm_response = ssm_client.get_parameter(Name = tmp)
        region_name = ssm_response['Parameter']['Value'] 
        regions[region_id] = region_name
    return(regions)


def rds_worksheet_creation(spread_sheet, regions, spreadsheet_index):
    worksheet = spread_sheet.add_worksheet("RDS", rows=100, cols=26, src_tuple=None, src_worksheet=None, index=spreadsheet_index)
    worksheet.cell('A1').set_text_format('bold', True).value = 'DBInstanceIdentifier'
    worksheet.cell('B1').set_text_format('bold', True).value = 'MasterUsername'
    worksheet.cell('C1').set_text_format('bold', True).value = 'Region'
    worksheet.cell('D1').set_text_format('bold', False).value = 'Sent Query to (Name)'
    worksheet.cell('E1').set_text_format('bold', False).value = 'Sent Query to (email)'
    worksheet.cell('F1').set_text_format('bold', False).value = 'WorksheetCreated: %s' % currentDT
    cells_data = list()
    for region, region_h in sorted(regions.items()):
        client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
        clnt = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=region)
        db_instances = client.describe_db_instances()
        for instance in db_instances['DBInstances']:
            MasterUsername = instance['MasterUsername']
            DBInstanceIdentifier = instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']
            cells_data.append([DBInstanceIdentifier, MasterUsername, region_h])
    worksheet.append_table(cells_data, start='A2')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spread_sheet = create_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_name = "jSonar AWS usage",
                                                            outh_file = '/home/qa/.aws/client_secret.json')
    regions = get_regions()
    rds_worksheet_creation(spread_sheet, regions, 0)
    spread_sheet.share("me@corp.com")
```

### Output:

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. Your output image is the result you want? If it's the current result, can you provide the result you want? 2. Can I ask you about ``all the cells starting at A2.``? 2. Can I ask you about ``i.e., in one command``?

Comment: {1} The image, @Tanaike, shows the current results. {2} all the rows 2-20.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to un-bold multiple cells in single command.

To set format to a range of cells create a Datarange and use `apply_format`.

```
model_cell = Cell('A1')
model_cell.set_text_format('bold', False)
Datarange('A1','A10', worksheet=wks).apply_format(model_cell)
```

[docs](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/staging/datarange.html#pygsheets.DataRange.apply_format)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @nithin.
If I want all cells after 'A2' to be unbolded, is there a more elegant way to do that than to use `Datarange('A1','Z99999', worksheet=wks).apply_format(model_cell)`? (I tried removing the end_cell argument, but got `pygsheets.exceptions.InvalidArgumentValue: addr of type <class 'NoneType'>`)

Comment: there is no inbuild way to skip this. but you can do `Datarange('A1',(1, wks.cols), worksheet=wks)`

Comment: I don't think that's the correct way to get all non-heading lines to be bolded (it only unbolded the first row). I eventually used (the still non-elegant): `pygsheets.DataRange(start_cell, "ZZ%s" % worksheet.rows, worksheet=worksheet).apply_format(model_cell)`